# Adobe Air Mobile: how to put text on splash screen

Tags: android, mobile, air, adobe, splash-screen

is it possible to add some text information to splash screen – for example: application version (build) or some date ?

Answer (score 0):

No, the splash screen is an image.
But, what you can do is to make and image with the text.